# How should I change my code so that I can call the Bind() function instead of using the event table?

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I am using **WxWidgets 3.2** for my **C++** **Windows** application.

I need to pass data (eg login) from one class to another. To do this, I create a custom event and use the event table to bind the event to the handler.

For example, I have a LoginPanel class and I want to pass the login entered by the user to another class - MainFrame.

LoginPanel.h

```
DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE(LOGIN_ENTERED, wxCommandEvent)

enum class Buttons_ID {
    ID_CONNECT_BUTTON = wxID_HIGHEST + 1,
};

class LoginPanel : public wxPanel {
public:
    LoginPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY);

private:
    void OnConnectButton(wxCommandEvent& event);
    wxTextCtrl* usernameInput;
};
```

LoginPanel.cpp

```
DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE(LOGIN_ENTERED)
LoginPanel::LoginPanel(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id)
    : wxPanel(parent, id) {
    wxButton* connectButton = new wxButton(loginTab, wxID_ANY, "Connect");
    connectButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &LoginPanel::OnConnectButton, this);
}

void LoginPanel::OnConnectButton(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    wxString username = usernameInput->GetValue();
    wxCommandEvent loginEvent(LOGIN_ENTERED, GetId());
    loginEvent.SetString(username);
    GetParent()->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(loginEvent);
}
```

MainFrame.h

```
class MainFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MainFrame(const wxString& title);
    ~MainFrame();

private:
    LoginPanel * loginPanel;           

public:
    void ShowLoginPanel();
    void OnLoginEntered(wxCommandEvent& event);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE(); 
};
```

MainFrame.cpp

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ChessFrame, wxFrame)                             
    EVT_COMMAND(wxID_ANY, LOGIN_ENTERED, ChessFrame::OnLoginEntered) 
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()                                                  

MainFrameFrame::MainFrameFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wxRESIZE_BORDER) {
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    loginPanel = new LoginPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    mainSizer->Add(loginPanel, 1, wxEXPAND);
    SetSizer(mainSizer);
    ShowLoginPanel();
}

void MainFrameFrame::OnLoginEntered(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    auto login = event.GetString();
}
```

This is how the code works and the **LOGIN_ENTERED** event is normally passed from the LoginPanel class to the OnConnectButton() handler of the MainFrame class.

Since using the event table is not very modern now, I want to use the Bind() function. I call the Bind() function in the constructor of the MainFrame class:

```
loginPanel->Bind(LOGIN_ENTERED, &ChessFrame::OnLoginEntered, this);
```

However, the problem is that an error occurs:

```
C2664: 'void wxEventFunctorMethod<EventTag,ChessFrame,EventArg,EventHandler>::CheckHandlerArgument(EventArg *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'wxEvent *' to 'EventArg *'
```

How should I change my code so that I can call the Bind() function instead of using the event table?

Comment: @joe_dawson, I presume you did see this: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_events.html#overview_events_custom_existing?

Comment: And so I urge you to follow the official documentation and change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is the macro you're using to declare/define your new events.  You should use [wxDECLARE_EVENT](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#ga767b12d37f7370bc5f6b3d62340f3ef8) and [wxDEFINE_EVENT](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#ga09ec1d095bee3085c1cb31459b46bc00) instead.

In short, change

```
DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE(LOGIN_ENTERED, wxCommandEvent)
```

to

```
wxDECLARE_EVENT(LOGIN_ENTERED, wxCommandEvent);
```

and

```
DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE(LOGIN_ENTERED)
```

to

```
wxDEFINE_EVENT(LOGIN_ENTERED, wxCommandEvent);
```

Also, I would suggest changing

```
GetParent()->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(loginEvent);
```

to simply

```
ProcessWindowEvent(loginEvent);
```

Command events will filter up to the parent windows if not handled by the window itself.

Comment: thx for putting better explanation. Most likely those macros comes from the older version of wx somehow...

Comment: @new-pagodi, could you clarify how do I pass the event in the opposite direction: from class MainFrame to class LoginPanel ? Now I am using the expression: loginPanel->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(event_fromMainFrame)

Comment: If you want to do that, that code should would work.  But usually you wouldn't pass events from a parent to a child.  If a child needs to needs to be updated in some way based on some event detected in the parent, usually you would just have the parent call whatever of the child's methods to do the updating.